# Javascript regex only matching entire url as typing

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use javascript to find all URLs in a textarea as the person is typing (onkeyup). The problem that I'm having is in finding a regex to match the entire URL, I need it only to match all the URL's in the text area that are complete URLs.

All of the existing regex expressions that I find through Google and through my own experiementing seem to match as soon as the user has typed the first part of the pattern. So, for example, if I'm typing and then start to type http://w, all of a sudden, it will match.

I need to find a regex that will match and return an array of all the urls that are in the textarea, while also not matching unless the person has completed typing the full URL. Hopefully that makes sense!

Thank you!

Comment: http://w is a complete URI.

Comment: ok, well i would like only to find patterns like:

http://domain.com

or http://www.domain.com

or http://www.domain.com:8080

or https://domain.com/whatever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David's comment is right.

How could you ever determine that `http://www.domain.com/whatever` was a complete URL but `http://www.domain.com/what` wasn't? Or `http://www.domain.com` is complete but `http://www.domain.co` isn't? (It is, there's a real site there).

You might disallow hostnames without a `.` in, but then why shouldn't `http://to` be valid? (It is, there's a real site there.) Not to mention `http://テスト`.

There is no possible consistent answer to the question “what is the regex to match things that *look like* URLs *to me*”.

Comment: I think I can require that there is a space (or punctuation) after for the purposes of "monitoring" the text box. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Careful, a lot of trailing punctuation is valid in URLs too! eg. `.,!?)`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this pattern:

```
   var pattern = /((https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])(\s|\.\s|\,\s|\n|\r|\n\r)/ig;
```

That checks for the existence of either a space or a carriage return (in conjunction with a comma or a period, I'll probably have to add some other cases), and then I remove the period or comma after.